# Coding Java in NetBeans: How To Rename All Occurrence of A Variable At Once?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm coding Java using NetBeans IDE. How do I rename all the occurrence of a variable at once?

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring

Comment: Ctrl-R will rename the variables

Comment: Just double-click on the variable then hit Ctrl-R. If you're done typing, hit Esc. http://gph.is/2n5kQzC

Comment: Hello. This question has been edited. Should it be reopened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you change (rename) all of those highlighted variables at once:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring

[image]

And I don't use Netbeans, but I believe this should help you to disable the occurrence marking (highlighting):

`Options->Fonts & Colors ->
Syntax, language: Java, Category: Mark Occurrences.`

From [HERE](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Turn-off-or-change-the-automatic-highlight-of-the-mark-occurrence-feature-td2949743.html).

Comment: it works in the php but does not apply in html context